# How to stop Outlook from blocking ANY attachments?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, attachments

There is a long list of [file extensions blocked by Outlook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/blocked-attachments-in-outlook-HA001229952.aspx). I've found instructions on which registry setting to [stop single file extensions from being blocked](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829982), but I don't want Outlook to block any attachments at all.

Is there a way to do that other than adding the whole extension list (ade;adp;app;asp;...) to that registry setting? Thunderbird opens the files just fine, so I know it's a client-side setting.

Comment: The page you linked to explains how to unblocked multiple file extensions

Comment: @Ramhound I'm aware of that. But there must be a better way than putting that entire long list into a semicolon-delimited string. For one, I'd need to update it whenever Microsoft decided to block yet another extension that overlaps with one that I commonly use.

Comment: You should revise your question to reflect that fact because you indicate the link is only for a single file extension.  The otherway involves your Exchange Admin.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, I mean "single file extensions" in the sense of "one at a time".

Answer (score 0):

I think [Outlooktools](http://www.howto-outlook.com/products/outlooktools.htm), the free 3rd party tool will help you..

Reffered [here](http://www.howto-outlook.com/faq/blockedattachments.htm)...